# Initialize object in NHibernate session by id

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have this code for saving my object to database and it work fine.

```
    public int CreateOrder(OrderDB orderDB)
    {
        using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    session.SaveOrUpdate(orderDB.Car);
                    session.SaveOrUpdate(orderDB.Owner);

                    for (int i = 0; i < orderDB.Service.Count; i++)
                    {
                        session.SaveOrUpdate(orderDB.Service[i]);
                    }
                    session.SaveOrUpdate(orderDB);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        return orderDB.ID;
    }
```

Entities:

```
public class OrderDB:BasicRecordDB
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Service> Service { get; set; }

    public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }

    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

    public virtual Box Box { get; set; }

    public virtual double TotalPrise { get; set; }

    public virtual int OrderNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual string CarNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }

}
```

And for example entity Model (in Car) already contains in database and for saving Order should be enough just Model ID but now it send from Client to Server all entity Car and model with all properties. Haw can I save order if I will send just entity id (I mean just that entity which already in database and have private key)?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Requesting a `Car` from the database shouldn't normally request the data for the `Model` as it most likely is lazy-loaded.

Comment: Problem is when I want to save order I send from my client application to my server application all Order with all sub-entity and they property. But it's for saving my order does'n need all properties in all sub-entity, for some entity will enough send just id. So I want send just id when it's possibly.

Comment: An unrelated note but there is no sense in just re-throwing an exception if you aren't going to do anything with it.  Take the try catch block out if that's all that it does.

Comment: Thank you for your notes, I left it's like this for now, I'll fill catch later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I am using approach of two properties, representing one `column` in different way: *Reference* and *ReferenceId*.

So let's extend the Car class first:

```
public class Car
{
  ...
  Model _model 

  public virtual Model Model
  { 
   get { return _model; } 
   set 
   {
     _model = value;
     ModelId = _model.ID;
   } 
  }

  public virtual int ModelId { get; set; }
}
```

So, now we can directly

1. set `ModelId` or
2. set the reference to `Model` instance

in both cases `ModelId` has correct value.

And NHibernate mapping

```
<many-to-one name="Model" column="ModelId" insert="false" update="false"   />
<property  name="ModelId" column="ModelId/>
```

Well, the only persisted property is the `ModelId`. But, the Reference `Model` is fully working for filtering, navigation... And you can send your `Car` instance with int property only...